# Better looking function

Tags: javascript, chart.js

```
 function changeToSeven() {
        barChart.data.datasets[0].data = newConfirmedCases.slice(Math.max(newConfirmedCases.length - 7, 0));
        barChart.data.datasets[1].data = newConfirmedRecovered.slice(Math.max(newConfirmedRecovered.length - 7, 0));
        barChart.data.datasets[2].data = newConfirmedDeaths.slice(Math.max(newConfirmedDeaths.length - 7, 0));
        barChart.data.labels = formatedDates.slice(Math.max(formatedDates.length - 7, 0));
        barChart.update();
    }

    function changeToThirty() {
        barChart.data.datasets[0].data = newConfirmedCases.slice(Math.max(newConfirmedCases.length - 30, 0));
        barChart.data.datasets[1].data = newConfirmedRecovered.slice(Math.max(newConfirmedRecovered.length - 30, 0));
        barChart.data.datasets[2].data = newConfirmedDeaths.slice(Math.max(newConfirmedDeaths.length - 30, 0));
        barChart.data.labels = formatedDates.slice(Math.max(formatedDates.length - 30, 0));
        barChart.update();
    }

    function changeToNinety() {
        barChart.data.datasets[0].data = newConfirmedCases.slice(Math.max(newConfirmedCases.length - 90, 0));
        barChart.data.datasets[1].data = newConfirmedRecovered.slice(Math.max(newConfirmedRecovered.length - 90, 0));
        barChart.data.datasets[2].data = newConfirmedDeaths.slice(Math.max(newConfirmedDeaths.length - 90, 0));
        barChart.data.labels = formatedDates.slice(Math.max(formatedDates.length - 90, 0));
        barChart.update();
    }


    function changeToBeginning() {
        barChart.data.datasets[0].data = newConfirmedCases;
        barChart.data.datasets[1].data = newConfirmedRecovered;
        barChart.data.datasets[2].data = newConfirmedDeaths;
        barChart.data.labels = formatedDates;
        barChart.update();
    }


    document.getElementById("defaultState").addEventListener("click", changeToBeginning);
    document.getElementById("lastSeven").addEventListener("click", changeToSeven);
    document.getElementById("lastThirty").addEventListener("click", changeToThirty);
    document.getElementById("lastNinety").addEventListener("click", changeToNinety);
```

I want to write only one function (or make it look beeter), which works like those 4. I know it can't be hard, but i don't know what argument i need in if statement. The HTML element's are buttons to change data range on chart.js. I am a beginner in JS, so any help could be useful.

Comment: At first I thought this was a joke. But if you really don't know, you've written your answer/solution in the name of each function. Change `changeToSeven()` etc. to `changeTo(number)` where `number` would be `7`, `30`, `90` that you substitute in to the function in place of the literal value. You could use custom `data-` attributes on the buttons to provide the values.

Comment: If it would be that easy, I wouldn't be writing any question. I am getting "undefined" of barChart.data if i make a similar function like you written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's a revised version** of your code that shows how to accomplish what you're trying to do. (I wasn't sure what your `barChart` object looks like, so I substituted something relatively simple that should be close enough for demo purposes.)

Each button has a "data attribute" called `number` whose **value gets passed to the `changeTo` function** so the correct number of elements will be shown.  (It's fine, if you prefer, to use the `changeTo` function itself as the listener function instead of using a separate `handleClick` function that calls `changeTo` -- you would just need to move `handleClick`'s logic, including retrieving the `number`, to inside of `changeTo`.)

The code is shortened a bit further by putting the data arrays (`newConfirmedCases`, etc.) into **an array of arrays, which parallels the `barChart.data.datasets`** array of `.data` objects -- this lets us copy (the desired part of) each data array into the corresponding `.data` object within a loop, according to its index (`i`) in `datasets`.

**See the in-code comments** for further clarifications. And look up anything you want to know more about on MDN (eg "data attributes", "arrow functions", "event listeners", or "foreach").

```js
const
  // Simulates your barChart object for initial display
  barChart = getBarChart();

  // Simulates your data arrays
  newConfirmedCases =     [11, 22, 33, 44, 55],
  newConfirmedRecovered = [ 5, 10, 15, 20, 25],
  newConfirmedDeaths =    [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
  formattedDates = ["1/1/21", "1/2/21", "1/3/21", "1/4/21", "1/5/21"],

  // Identifies relevant DOM elements
  buttonContainer = document.getElementById("buttonContainer");
  
  // Calls handler func when anything in buttonContainer is clicked
  buttonContainer.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
  
  // Triggers initial display of all data
  changeTo("Infinity");


  // Defines listener function
  function handleClick(event){ // Listener knows about triggering event
    const clickedThing = event.target; // Event has useful properties
    if(clickedThing.tagName != "BUTTON"){ return; } // Ignores irrelevant clicks

    // Gets number from custom attribute; passes it to `changeTo`
    changeTo(clickedThing.getAttribute("data-number"));
  }


  // Defines the function that does the heavy lifting
  function changeTo(howMany) {
    // - Takes a number (including JS's global "infinity")
    // - Updates barChart object, then updates display

    const
      // Simulates barChart object for local use
      barChart = getBarChart(),

      // Makes a `datasets` matrix (an array of arrays)
      datasets = [newConfirmedCases, newConfirmedRecovered, newConfirmedDeaths];

    // Applies an anonymous function to each array in matrix
    datasets.forEach( (dataset, i) => {

      const whereToSliceData = Math.max(dataset.length - howMany, 0);

      // Left side is the corresponding array from inside `barChart`
      // Right side is a slice of the current array from matrix
      barChart.data.datasets[i].data = dataset.slice(whereToSliceData);
    });

    // A similar process sets barChart's labels
    const whereToSliceDates = Math.max(formattedDates.length - howMany, 0);
    barChart.data.labels = formattedDates.slice(whereToSliceDates);

    // Finally, calls `.update` method to change the display
    barChart.update();
  }

  // Mostly ignore this, just simulates your barChart obj (poorly)
  function getBarChart(){
    const barChart = {
      data: {
        datasets: [{},{},{}],
        labels: []
      },
      update: function(){
        const display = document.getElementById("display");
        display.innerHTML = "";
        for (let dataset of this.data.datasets){
          for (let datum of dataset.data){
            const spaces = 8 - datum.toString().length;
            display.innerHTML += "&nbsp;".repeat(spaces) + datum;
          }
          display.innerHTML += "<br/>";
        }
        display.innerHTML += "<br/>" + "&nbsp;".repeat(3);
        for (let label of this.data.labels){
          display.innerHTML += "&nbsp;".repeat(2) + label;
        }
      }
    }
    return barChart;
  }
```

```css
#display{ font-family: monospace; }
```

```html
<div id="buttonContainer">
  <button data-number="Infinity">Default</button>
  <button data-number="2">Last Two</button>
  <button data-number="3">Last Three</button>
  <button data-number="4">Last Four</button>
</div>
<hr/>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: The answer is recently edited because I was rereading the code and noticed a bug in the click listener. It said `if (!clickedThing.tagName == "BUTTON")`, which could never possibly be true. The resulting behavior was that some clicks would update the display to an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

You could implement a solution that both cleans up and adds flexibility to your code, which is to create a single `changeTo()` function, taking as argument the number of days you would like to slice your `newConfirmed...` array.

Additionally, you could use a map to save the index of `datasets` as key and the corresponding `newConfirmed...` array as value.

Eventually, add the `eventListeners` by calling the `changeTo()` function for the amount of days you require.

```
//Key of map is dataset index, value is newConfirmed array
let map = new Map();
map.set(0, newConfirmedCases);
map.set(1, newComfirmedRecovered);
map.set(2, newConfirmedDeaths);

//This operation is done multiple times in your code, let's make it a function
function slicer(val, number) {
    return val.slice(Math.max(val.length - number, 0));
}

function changeTo(number = 0) {
    //Iterate through map and set data
    //If number is 0, whole array is returned, else the sliced array
    for (const [key, val] of map.entries()) 
        barChart.data.datasets[key].data = (number) ? slicer(val, number) : val;

    barChart.data.labels = (number) ? slicer(formattedDates, number) : formattedDates;
    barChart.update()
}

//Set eventListeners by calling changeTo() for the required amount of days
//Remember that if you give no argument, it will act like former changeToBeginning
document.getElementById("defaultState").addEventListener("click", changeTo());
document.getElementById("lastSeven").addEventListener("click", changeTo(7));
document.getElementById("lastThirty").addEventListener("click", changeTo(30));
document.getElementById("lastNinety").addEventListener("click", changeTo(90));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function updateUI() {
    updateStats();
    chartDrawing();
}

barChart = new Chart(chartTwo, {
        type: "bar",
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                    label: "Nowych Zarażeń",
                    data: newConfirmedCases,
                    fill: false,
                    borderColor: "gray",
                    backgroundColor: "crimson",
                    borderWidth: 1,
                },
                {
                    label: "Nowych Ozdrowień",
                    data: newConfirmedRecovered,
                    fill: false,
                    borderColor: "gold",
                    backgroundColor: "green",
                    borderWidth: 1,
                },
                {
                    label: "Nowych Zgonów",
                    data: newConfirmedDeaths,
                    fill: false,
                    borderColor: "brown",
                    backgroundColor: "coral",
                    borderWidth: 1,
                },
            ],
            labels: formatedDates,
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
        }
    })
```

The rest of a code, unfortunately i am getting "undefined" of barChart.data.
The chartDrawing function have all the code in itself.